# Difference between storing values in character pointer with malloc and without

Tags: c++, c, malloc

I have a character pointer like this

```
  char *ptr;
```

I can allocate values to it like this

```
  *ptr='a';
  *(ptr+1)='b';
```

Now when I can do this, why should I use an malloc?

Am I just lucky that this pointer is not referencing an address that is being used by a process? Or are there chances that my data will be corrupted by someother process if I don't use 'malloc'?

Comment: You aren't "allocating" values; you are *assigning* values to an unallocated memory region. It's undefined behavior (as @SeigeX says) and is extremely dangerous.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Am I just lucky that this pointer is
>   not referencing an address that is
>   being used by a process?

No, you're not lucky.  If you were lucky, the program would crash so you know you have a problem.  As written, your code is **Undefined Behavior**.  You are writing data through a pointer to unallocated memory.

> § 6.5.6/8
> If both the
>   pointer operand and the result point
>   to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the
>   array object, the evaluation shall not
>   produce an overflow; **otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.**

Comment: @Shyam: "Works on my machine" is not a situation where a programmer calls himself lucky, usually ;).

Comment: @Shyam we must have different definitions for 'lucky' then. I'd rather know that my code has undefined behavior during development than getting a call on the weekend because it just crashed on one of our customer's systems.